# Logstash HTTP input plugin configuration error: Expected one of #

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

I am attempting to configure the logstash HTTP input plugin following the official [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/blog/introducing-logstash-input-http-plugin). I have the following config saved in the **10-syslog.conf**

```
input {
   port => 8080
   user => elkadmin
   password => "xxxx"
   ssl => off
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    host => "127.0.0.1"
   codec => "json"
    index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    protocol => "http"
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Logstash does start successfully when using the following command:

```
sudo service logstash restart
```

I have ran the configuration check on the configuration file for the input plugin using the

`/opt/logstash/bin/logstash -configtest -f 10-syslog.conf`

The config check came back with the following error:

> Error: Expected one of #, { at line 2, column 9 (byte 18) after input {

Looking at the logstash log I can see that it may be caused by permissions:

> {:timestamp=>"2016-10-16T20:41:30.900000+0000", :message=>"The error reported is: \n  Permission denied - /etc/logstash/conf.d/10-syslog.conf"}

I am very much unsure how to proceed here and any help and/or guidance would be more than appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're simply missing the name of the `http` input plugin in your input section (the typo comes from the blog article you linked to)

```
input {
  http {                   <--- add this
    port => 8080
    user => elkadmin
    password => "xxxx"
    ssl => off
  }
}
```

Also note that in your `elasticsearch` output plugin, `host` should read `hosts`and `protocol` is not supported anymore.

Your link is old (from 2015), you should preferably use the latest documentation at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-http.html

Comment: Val, thanks for this. I have made the required changes but interestingly the hosts value was incorrect and config test was not happy and host seems to be the correct. On the side note I am still getting the access denied on the 10-syslog.conf but logstash starts-up normally, have you got any pointers how to set-up correct permissions?

Comment: Your logstash can't access the file `10-syslog.conf`. How are you starting Logstash? With sudo? What are the permissions on the `10-syslog.conf`  file?

Comment: `host` is probably correct because you're using Logstash 1.5.2 which is an old version. I would strongly encourage you to use the [latest Logstash version](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/logstash) instead.

Comment: I am starting the service with sudo, and the permissions on this file seem to be quite strange, when running `ls -la` I am getting the following for the `10-syslog.conf`: `---------- 1 root root  232 Oct 17 07:41 10-syslog.conf`

Comment: Indeed, you need to fix that, also you should not start Logstash with sudo.

Comment: Thanks for that, Which account should have permissions to that file? Is there a guide on the specific permissions required?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32036002/unable-to-run-logstash-config-file-permission-denied